# Adding GeoFire dependency with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, geofire

I'm working with Firebase on iOS, and I want to add GeoFire. I am following the instructions here: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc, but after adding pod 
    'GeoFire', '>=1.1'
to my podfile and updating I get the error

```
$ pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Firebase (~> 2.1)` required by `GeoFire (1.1.0)`

Specs satisfying the `Firebase (~> 2.1)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

My podfile look like

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '8.1'

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'

pod 'GeoFire', '>=1.1'

target 'FriendlyChatSwift' do
end
```

I'm not to sure whats going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps in order as one of them should fix the problem:

1. Update Cocoapods to latest release (1.0.1).
2. In your project podfile delete the pod 'GeoFire', '>=1.1' line.
3. In terminal go to the folder where your project is and run:

   pod update
4. Now go back to the Podfile and add GeoFire this way:

   pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'
5. In terminal go to the folder where your project is and run:

   pod install
6. For good measure I run a pod update again after the install, just in case (BLACK MAGIC?)
7. Normally you would be done and good to go BUT there is currently a major bug but luckily after many hours the community has found a fix- navigate in XCode Project navigator to: Pods -> Pods -> Firebase Database -> Frameworks -> SELECT/HIGHLIGHT FirebaseDatabase.framework
8. After selecting/highlighting FirebaseDatabase.framework look at the File Inspector (far right, paper icon) and select/checkmark GeoFire under Target Membership.

Here is a link to a screenshot for steps 7/8: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1798166/16071528/6e625fd8-330e-11e6-97ca-655bea333fbb.png

Finally make sure you check out the "Issues" section of the project on GitHub - it's a great resource and you might find a solution there in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What version of cocoapods are you using? They just recently released 1.0. You may want to try that.

Also, here is the latest geofire podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "GeoFire"
  s.version      = "1.1.2"
  s.summary      = "Realtime location queries with Firebase."
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc"
  s.license      = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author       = { "Firebase" => "support@firebase.com" }
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git", :tag => 'v1.1.2' }
  s.source_files = "GeoFire/**/*.{h,m}"
  s.docset_url   = "https://geofire-ios.firebaseapp.com/docs/"
  s.ios.deployment_target = '7.0'
  s.osx.deployment_target = '10.10'
  s.ios.dependency  'Firebase', '~> 2.2'
  s.osx.dependency  'FirebaseOSX', '~> 2.4'
  s.framework = 'CoreLocation'
  s.requires_arc = true
end
```

Try pulling geofire 1.1.x in your podfile.